# If $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $C^{k+1}$ and $f(0) = 0$, is $g_i(x)=\int_0^1 D_if(hx)$, $C^k$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, partial-derivative

If $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $C^{k+1}$ and $f(0) = 0$, is $g_i(x)=\int_0^1 D_if(hx)$, $C^k$? Where $h$ is a constant real number.

To me it seems like it should be $C^{k+1}$ since $D_if(x)$ will be $C^k$ and the integral of a $C^k$ function is $C^{k+1}$.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see where is the problem even in the case $m=1$. (The assumption $f(0) = 0$ does not play any role.)
So, assume that $f\in C^{k+1}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $g(x) := \int_0^1 f'(hx)\, dh$.
Clearly $g(0) = f'(0)$. For $x\neq 0$, using the equality
$$
\frac{d}{dh} [ f(hx) ] = x\, f'(hx)
$$
you get
$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dh} [ f(hx) ] \, dh
= \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}\,.
$$
Hence the function $g$ is
$$
g(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}\,, & x\neq 0,\\
f'(0)\,, & x=0.
\end{cases}
$$
If $f\in C^{k+1}$, then this function $g$ is of class $C^k$.

Comment: Is there anyway to make it $C^{k+1}$? What conditions on $f$ other than making it $C^{k+2}$ can make $g$ $C^{k+1}$?

Comment: I do not see any good condition. Consider, for example, $f$ defined by $f(x) = 0$ if $x\leq 0$, $f(x) = x^{\alpha}$ for $x> 0$, with $\alpha > 1$. Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $k+1 < \alpha\leq k+2$. You can check that $f \in C^{k+1}$ but $g$ is only of class $C^k$.